# convert flat XML to nested using for-each-group

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have to admit to failing miserably to understand how to use for-each-group. I've tried group-by, group-adjacent and I get arbitrary results that defy my understanding of what I've done wrong.

I have the following input XML which is 'flat': all the elements inside   are siblings and I need to transform it to create a nested structure.

```
<document>
<separator style="XXX"/>
<paragraph style="aaa">
    <p>text1</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="bbb">
    <p>text2</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="list1">
    <p>text3</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="list1">
    <p>text4</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="list1">
    <p>text5</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="ccc">
    <p>text6</p>
</paragraph>
<separator style="YYY"/>
<paragraph style="ddd">
    <p>text7</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="ddd">
    <p>text8</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="ddd">
    <p>text9</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="list1">
    <p>text10</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="list1">
    <p>text11</p>
</paragraph>
<paragraph style="ddd">
    <p>text12</p>
</paragraph>
```

I need the following output:

```
<document>
<separator style="XXX">
    <paragraph style="aaa">
        <p>text1</p>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph style="bbb">
        <p>text2</p>
    </paragraph>
    <list>
        <paragraph style="list1">
            <p>text3</p>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph style="list1">
            <p>text4</p>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph style="list1">
            <p>text5</p>
        </paragraph>
    </list>
    <paragraph style="ccc">
        <p>text6</p>
    </paragraph>
</separator>
<separator style="YYY">
    <paragraph style="ddd">
        <p>text7</p>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph style="ddd">
        <p>text8</p>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph style="ddd">
        <p>text9</p>
    </paragraph>
    <list>
        <paragraph style="list1">
            <p>text10</p>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph style="list1">
            <p>text11</p>
        </paragraph>
    </list>
</separator>
```

I've not included any XSL that I've already tried as it is obviously incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are not spelled out by a single sample but check whether the [XSLT sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22document%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22*%22%20group-starting-with%3D%22separator%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22tail%28current-group%28%29%29%22%20group-adjacent%3D%22%40style%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22starts-with%28current-grouping-key%28%29%2C%20%27list%27%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clist%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flist%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Cdocument%3E%0D%0A%3Cseparator%20style%3D%22XXX%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22aaa%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext1%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22bbb%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext2%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22list1%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext3%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22list1%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext4%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22list1%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext5%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22ccc%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext6%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cseparator%20style%3D%22YYY%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22ddd%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext7%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22ddd%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext8%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22ddd%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext9%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22list1%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext10%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22list1%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext11%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3Cparagraph%20style%3D%22ddd%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext12%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fparagraph%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdocument%3E%0D%0A&input-type=XML) helps (`tail` is XPath/XSLT 3, use `subsequence(current-group(), 2)` if you really are stuck with XSLT 2):

```
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="separator">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-adjacent="@style">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="starts-with(current-grouping-key(), 'list')">
                <list>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </list>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is utterly brilliant. Thank you so much.  There is no way my trial-and-error method of trying every permutation of group-by, group-adjacent, etc would ever have succeeded.

I had to change the tail to subsequence - and that worked first time.  Brilliant. Thanks again.